# Login Activity with MainActivity on Back button press

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a problem with Activities. My `MainActivity` is a first activity. After succesful loggin in, i want to come back to MainActivity. When login is not succed, user stayed on `LoginActivity`. **`MainActivity`** looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent activityIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activityIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(activityIntent);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
}
```

And **`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.admin.keystroke_dynamics">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.SignupActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark" />
</application>
```

I close **`LoginActivity`** by method `finish();`, when login credentials are correct. When user pass wrong data into EditTextes, User stay in Login Page.

My question is, how to close app to tab on `Back` button press, when user is not login in? For now, when User is not logged, on back button press i come back to MainActivity. I want to close app to work in background, if noone is loged in.

Comment: Start `startActivityForResult()` from `MainActivity` to launch `LoginActivity`. Then use `setResult` from the `LoginActivity` before calling `finish()`. `Override` `onActivityResult()` in your `MainActivity` and check `resultCode` to see if you've logged in.

Comment: you can finish you mainActivity when loginActivity is open and if user sucessfully login you can start MainActivity again and if user not then on pressing back button app is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `startActivityForResult()` mechanism to start LoginActivity with a requestCode.

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class), <Request-Code>);`

Then in LoginActivity you need to call setResult() if the user logs in successfully before finishing your activity.

`setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();`

To consume this result, you need to override `onActivityResult()` in your MainActivity -

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
         // check if the request code is same with which you requested LoginActivity
         if(requestCode == <Request-Code>){
               if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                   // now finish your activity
                   finish();
               }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more complex example for me? How `<request-code>` looks like? By this mechanism i can "block" `Back` button to go to `MainActivity` when user is not login in?

Comment: <request-code> is an integer value if you look at the startActivityForResult() method declaration. 
Where and why do you think you are blocking the user with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this..

```
if{
    //CODE FOR SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN
 }else{
     Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```